# multiple mysql query's for multiple file uploads

Tags: php, mysql

I have a multiple file upload with php and I want to create insert a mysql row for each file uploaded. so for example if 3 files were uploaded: a.txt, b.txt and c.txt, it would create 3 insert querys one where $filename was a.txt the second b.txt and the third 3.txt. is this possible?

```
$target = "test/";

    if($target[strlen($target)-1]!='/')
            $target=$target.'/';
        $count=0;
        foreach ($_FILES['uploaded']['name'] as $filename)
        {
            $temp=$target;
            $tmp=$_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'][$count];
            $count=$count + 1;
            $temp=$temp.basename($filename);
            move_uploaded_file($tmp,$temp);
            $temp='';
            $tmp='';
        }

//for each file uploaded    mysql_query("INSERT INTO files VALUES('','$date','$filename')");
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But please note that `mysql` extension is deprecated and will eventually be removed. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure it's possible. Just add your mysql_query at the end of your foreach block.

Comment: oh yes, I didn't think of adding it to the upload block . Tested it and its working. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.

And since you are looping the uploaded files already. I would do the sql query in that same loop.

And: *POINTS AT THE BIG RED BOX AT http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php*

Comment: Just read your comment too. Its amazing how people totally ignore everyone shouting "DONT USE MYSQL_QUERY!" Most seem totally oblivious.